# How to setup authentication & replicaset with mongo container using docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, replicaset

let's say we have the following setup with no authentication...

#### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4.4.1
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js
    command: --bind_ip_all --replSet RepSet
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017
```

#### mongo-init.js

```js
rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "RepSet",
    version: 1,
    members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27017" }
    ]
  })
```

the above works and the replication is setup properly in single node replicaset mode but...

how does one enable mongo authentication with the above setup?

if i add the following environment variables to the `db` service, then the `rs.initiate()` from the `mongo-init.js` doesn't work. it complains that the server was started without replication.

```sh
  db:
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

apparently the mongo docker image entrypoint script strips out the `--replSet` argument during the initial setup if authentication credentials are used.

does anyone know a 'not so hacky' workaround to get this working?

cheers!

Comment: Can't you append a `createUser()` in your init script?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-a-mongodb-replica-set-using-docker-6d0b9ac00e49

Comment: can you review this link